# Text field show as link in related list page layout?

Tags: community, custom-field, page-layout

I have an object called asset which has a lookup to the objectDetails object. This object has two fields as below

API Name : `API_Name__c`  :  `object1__c`  [Lookup]

API Name : `APIName__c` : `object__c` [Text]  - Populated by trigger.

Now i am trying to show the text field as a link text in related list page layout [ behave as lookup] in asset related list page layout.

Dont want to show the original lookup here. Any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new formula field of type HYPERLINK, and use appropriate link and text from respective fields.